# How to add space between two scales in chart-js?

Tags: charts, chart.js, react-chartjs

I have a line chart where in the y-axis i have some numbers from 0 to x. Since the numbers are very close to each other i need to add some space between them. I can't see option to set this in chart-js. I am using this chart-js in react using react-chartjs

[image]

Here's the code

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';

const data = {
  labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: '',
      data: [120, 100, 250, 180, 380, 276, 190, 420],
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: 'rbg(255,255,255)',
      borderColor: '#62C8C8',
      borderWidth: 3,
    },
  ],
};

const options = {
  legend: {
    display: false,
  },
  elements: {
    point: {
      radius: 0,
    },
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          tickMarkLength: 0,
        },
        ticks: {
          padding: 10,
        },
      },
    ],
    yAxes: [
      {
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          stepSize: 100,
          padding: 10,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};

const LineChart = () => (
    <Line data={data} options={options} />
);

export default LineChart;
```

Comment: Could you share the code u used to create this chart?

Comment: Uploaded my code. Please check

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things you can do, increase the canvas height so the chart has physicly more space to display so the axis can display more, you can also change to version 3 of the lib where you can set the `stepSize` dynamicly with a calculation so it gives less ticks en thus bigger space between them

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        ticks: {
          stepSize: (c) => ((Math.max(...c.chart.data.datasets[0].data) - Math.min(...c.chart.data.datasets[0].data)) / 2)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.2/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```